414 Request-URI is too large
The below code works fine from outside of a docker container
import requests, browsercookie

cookie = browsercookie.chrome()
response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie, verify=False)
print(response.reason, response.status_code)

But when I try to run this inside a docker container, it gives me a 414 error. This is a bit confusing, since everything I read about this error suggests that it is an error that the server generates. However, the only difference here is the client I use - host vs. docker. What might be causing this and how do I fix it?
